# How would you translate: ' "trousse" fontaine parfumée'

Tags: vocabulaire

The whole sentence is:

> My order reaches  €150, I will receive a 15ml Eau de parfum Plumetis,
>   portable vaporizer branded "GALIMARD" , a "trousse" fontaine parfumée
>   and 5% discount.Offer not valid on the "Gift Vouchers"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the corresponding definition of "trousse" is:

> Boîte, étui, pochette de petites dimensions, groupant divers objets correspondant à un usage spécialisé

There are [other definitions](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/trousse/80020) if you're interrested.

You will most probably receive [something like this](http://galimard.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/cadeau-n%C2%B034.jpg) (image coming directly from the Galimard website, named "gift #34"), which is commonly named "Trousse de toilette"

The closest English word I can find is a "vanity case", I'm not sure though if it's an exact translation as it seems vanity cases tend to be a lot more sophisticated.

Comment: That might just be called a kit or a bag.